# grabbing only the first link in a row

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautifulsoup to scrape through a table. In this table each row has multiple links. I am only interested in the first link of each row. How can I skip over the other links of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [find()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) instead of `find_all()`. `find()` finds the first occurrence and stops:

> The find_all() method scans the entire document looking for results,
>   but sometimes you only want to find one result. If you know a document
>   only has one  tag, it’s a waste of time to scan the entire
>   document looking for more. Rather than passing in limit=1 every time
>   you call find_all, you can use the find() method.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <html>
... <head>
...     <title>Test</title>
... </head>
... <body>
...     <div>
...         <a href="">First Link</a>
...         <a href="">Second Link</a>
...         <a href="">Third Link</a>
...     </div>
... </body>
... </html>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find_all('a')
[<a href="">First Link</a>, <a href="">Secod Link</a>, <a href="">Third Link</a>]
>>> soup.find('a')
<a href="">First Link</a>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can do it:

```
## first find all the tr tags
trs =  soup.find_all("tr")

## then for each tr find the a tag from there
for tr in trs:
    tr.find("a")  ## finds the first link
```

Answer (score 0):

Was just working through this myself and so thought I would give my solution, which builds on @Sabuj Hassan's answer above.  The code below will pull each link and add it to a list called 'links' which can then be added to your df.  Hopefully this helps someone out there!

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = # Insert your URL here.
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

# List will hold the first link in each row.
links = []

# Look works through each row of the table, pulls back the first link, and then
# appends it to the links list.
if table.findAll("tr"):
    trs = table.findAll('tr')  
    for tr in trs:
        try:
            link = tr.find('a')['href'] # Finds the first link in a row
            links.append(link) # Appends that link to the links list.
        except:
                pass
else:
    pass
```